# How to run TensorFlow 2 in a distributed environment with Horovod?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-training

I have successfully set up the distributed environment and run the example with [Horovod](https://github.com/horovod/horovod). And I also know that if I want to run the benchmark on TensorFlow 1 in a distributed setup, e.g. 4 nodes, following the [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks), the submission should be:

```
$ horovodrun -np 16 -H server1:4,server2:4,server3:4,server4:4 \
    python scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/tf_cnn_benchmarks.py \
        --model resnet101 \
        --batch_size 64 \
        --variable_update horovod \
        --data_dir /path/to/imagenet/tfrecords \
        --data_name imagenet \
        --num_batches=2000
```

But now I want to run the TensorFlow 2 [official models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official), for example BERT model. What command should I use?